# Group facts in prolog by 3 variables

Tags: prolog, grouping

I'm having troubles grouping some facts in prolog by 3 different properties.
This is my knownledge base (a graph basically):

```
% entity(Label, Id)
% relationship(Type, Subject, Object)

entity('Person', id_0).

entity('Place', 1468).
relationship('wasIn', id_0, 1468).
entity('Place', 1367).
relationship('wasIn', 1468, 1367).
entity('Person', 1466).
relationship('wasIn', 1466, 1468).
entity('Place', 1478).
relationship('aliasOf', 1478, 1468).

entity('Place', 1052).
relationship('wasIn', id_0, 1052).
entity('Place', 1184).
relationship('wasIn', 1052, 1184).
entity('Person', 1048).
relationship('wasIn', 1048, 1052).

entity('Place', 1069).
relationship('wasIn', id_0, 1069).
entity('Place', 1070).
relationship('wasIn', 1069, 1070).
entity('Person', 1068).
relationship('wasIn', 1068, 1069).
```

I wanted to group relationships by each entity id and subject type, so to get something like:

```
[
    [
        [id_0, wasIn, Place],
        % because entities 1468, 1052, 1069 are Places
        [ relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1468),
          relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1052),
          relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1069)]
    ],
    [
        [id_0, wasIn, Some Other Subject Label],
        [relationship(wasIn, id_0, ...),
        ...]
    ],
    [
        [1468, wasIn, Place],
        [relationship(wasIn, 1468, ...),
        ...]
    ],
    ...
]
```

and so forth.

For now, I managed to group by subject and type only. Sadly, I'm getting duplicates out from it (which I wanted to avoid). Any further attempt I tried didn't work, that's why I'm asking here.
This are my current rules:

```
group_relationships_by_node([[Subject, Type] | [R]]) :-
    entity(_, Subject),
    relationship(Type, Subject, _),
    findall(relationship(Type, Subject, Object), relationship(Type, Subject, Object), R).

group_by_relationships(Result) :-
    findall(X, group_relationships_by_node(X), Result).
```

this is my current result:

```
[
  [
    [id_0, wasIn],
    [ relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1468),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1052),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1069) ]
  ],
  % duplicate
  [
    [id_0, wasIn],
    [ relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1468),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1052),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1069) ]
  ],
  % duplicate
  [
    [id_0, wasIn],
    [ relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1468),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1052),
      relationship(wasIn, id_0, 1069) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1468, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1468, 1367) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1466, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1466, 1468) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1478, aliasOf ],
    [ relationship(aliasOf, 1478, 1468) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1052, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1052, 1184) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1048, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1048, 1052) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1069, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1069, 1070) ]
  ],
  [
    [ 1068, wasIn ],
    [ relationship(wasIn, 1068, 1069) ]
  ]
]
```

Alas,
I don't know prolog very well myself,
I hope you can even suggest me a better solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So,

this is my attempt. It does work, but please let me know if a better solution exists (considering a dedup rule that removes duplicates from a list)

```
get_subject_ids(Subjects) :-
    findall(Subject, entity(_, Subject), Subjects).

get_relationship_by_type_subject_objectLabel(Type, Subject, ObjectLabel, Result) :-
    entity(ObjectLabel, Object),
    relationship(Type, Subject, Object),
    Result = relationship(Type, Subject, Object).

iterate_labels(_, _, [], []).
iterate_labels(Subject, Type, [ObjectLabel | Rest], [[ObjectLabel, Result] | ResultRest]) :-
    findall(Rel, get_relationship_by_type_subject_objectLabel(Type, Subject, ObjectLabel, Rel), Result),
    iterate_labels(Subject, Type, Rest, ResultRest).

iterate_objects([], []).
iterate_objects([Object | Rest], [ObjectLabel | ResultRest]) :-
    entity(ObjectLabel, Object),
    iterate_objects(Rest, ResultRest).

iterate_types(_, [], []).
iterate_types(Subject, [Type | Rest], [[Type, GroupedRels] | ResultRest]) :-
    % find all relationships with type Type starting from Subject
    % findall(relationship(Type, Subject, Object), relationship(Type, Subject, Object), Rels),
    findall(Object, relationship(Type, Subject, Object), Objects),
    iterate_objects(Objects, MObjects),
    dedup(MObjects, ObjectLabels),
    iterate_labels(Subject, Type, ObjectLabels, GroupedRels),
    iterate_types(Subject, Rest, ResultRest).

iterate_subjects([], []).
iterate_subjects([Subject | Rest], [[Subject, Result] | ResultRest]) :-
    findall(Type, relationship(Type, Subject, _), DTypes),
    dedup(DTypes, Types),
    iterate_types(Subject, Types, Result),
    iterate_subjects(Rest, ResultRest).

main :-
    get_subject_ids(Subjects),
    iterate_subjects(Subjects, Result),
    writeln(Result).
```

The result is something like:

```
[
  [
    id_0,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              id_0,
              1468),
              relationship(wasIn,
              id_0,
              1052)
            ]
          ],
          [
            Placez,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              id_0,
              1069)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1468,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1468,
              1367)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1367,
    [

    ]
  ],
  [
    1466,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1466,
              1468)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1478,
    [
      [
        aliasOf,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(aliasOf,
              1478,
              1468)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1052,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1052,
              1184)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1184,
    [

    ]
  ],
  [
    1048,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1048,
              1052)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1069,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Place,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1069,
              1070)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    1070,
    [

    ]
  ],
  [
    1068,
    [
      [
        wasIn,
        [
          [
            Placez,
            [
              relationship(wasIn,
              1068,
              1069)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

which is fine